# Undeclared object in Hibernate code causing confusion

Tags: java, hibernate

I am studying this book `Java Persistence with Hibernate` and on page 24 in the PDF version there is a statement like:

```
UserTransaction tx = TM.getUserTransaction();
```

I don't know where the `TM` comes from. I have googled for a while but can't find any answer. Because of this I can't run my code in Netbeans.

I can also see `JPA` somewhere in the code. What does that also mean?

The whole code is:

```
public class HelloWorldJPA {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HelloWorldPU");
            
            UserTransaction tx = TM.getUserTransaction();
            try {
                tx.begin();
            } catch (NotSupportedException | SystemException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldJPA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setText("Hello World!");
            
            em.persist(message);
            
            tx.commit();
            
            em.close();
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException | HeuristicRollbackException | IllegalStateException | RollbackException | SecurityException | SystemException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldJPA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TM is the Transaction Manager. JPA is the Java Persistence API.

Comment: @Jens What should i import to fix the problem?

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the code

Comment: @Jens I have added the code

Comment: perhaps it would be better to download the source code from Manning site  and look there instead of the excerpts in the book

Comment: I am stuck in the same example...these "in action" books are usually good, except for java persistence with hibernate. It is literally impossible for a newbie to follow it.

Answer (score 8):

1. TM is definitely an Instance Variable, usually set for single database connection manager per test suite
2. Please download the book source code from this [link](http://jpwh.org/examples/jpwh2/jpwh-2e-examples-20151103.zip)
3. Look for TransactionManagerTest.java class

   ```
   public class TransactionManagerTest {

   // Static single database connection manager per test suite
   static public TransactionManagerSetup TM;

   @Parameters({"database", "connectionURL"})
   @BeforeSuite()
   public void beforeSuite(@Optional String database,
                           @Optional String connectionURL) throws Exception {
       TM = new TransactionManagerSetup(
           database != null
               ? DatabaseProduct.valueOf(database.toUpperCase(Locale.US))
               : DatabaseProduct.H2,
           connectionURL
       );
   }

   @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
   public void afterSuite() throws Exception {
       if (TM != null)
           TM.stop();
   }
   }
   ```

   You will get the answer :-)
4. I would always recommend to get the source code online from manning publication sites for better practical understanding. They also upload their source code's in their [official site](https://www.manning.com/books/java-persistence-with-hibernate-second-edition) which is relevant to the current context.